# WildFly-10 - APIMAN Publish Issue

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, wildfly-10, apiman

I have wildfly 10 and installed APIMAN 1.5.1.APIMAN. Organization/API creation is done and while publishing the API, I'm getting below error

> io.apiman.manager.api.rest.contract.exceptions.ActionException: Failed to publish API.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue, in my case problem was with the ElasticSearch.

`apiman.es.host` defined in `standalone/configuration/apiman.properties` was not working.

Check host and port that are mentioned are open/working.